# Compactness of the set $(0, 1)$ as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, compactness

An open ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$, centered at the point $(1/2, 0)$ and of radius $1/2$ covers the segment $(0,1)$. The open ball thus forms a finite cover of $(0,1)$, implying that $(0,1)$ is a compact set. But that is wrong, for compact sets are closed. Can some one help me find the fallacy?

Answer (score 10):

A set $A$ is compact if **every** open cover of it has a finite subcover. You can always cover a set with one open set: the whole space is always an open set. Here, for instance, you could have covered the set with the single open set $\Bbb R^2$.

For $n\ge 3$ let $B_n$ be the open ball of radius $\frac12-\frac1n$ centred at $\left\langle\frac12,0\right\rangle$; then $\{B_n:n\ge 3\}$ is an open cover of the interval that does **not** have a finite subcover.

Comment: Hmpf. You win this round! :-P

Comment: @Asaf: Yes, but you just had a whole week when I was visiting friends $375$ miles from home and was able to be online much less than usual! :-)

Comment: But I was busy with other things for the past three weeks (I was relatively inactive, too)!

Comment: you both deserve gold stars

Comment: @Brian. Thanks to both. I was trying to find an open cover for both (0, 1) and [0, 1] hoping to show that it stayed being infinitely large for the former case and finite for the latter. I am yet to get it. Can you help me find it?

Comment: @Amey: You’re welcome. You’ll not find such an example: any open cover of $(0,1)$ that has no finite subcover will automatically **fail** to cover $[0,1]$. That’s because if it covers $[0,1]$, some finite subfamily of it will cover $[0,1]$ and therefore also cover $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 10):

Congratulations. You have found **a** finite cover of the set. But the condition for compactness is that **every** open cover has a finite subcover.